# Internal Server Error while deployoing Django 4.1 on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Please find given below my error log

```
Requirements.txt

asgiref==3.5.2'
astroid==2.11.7
certifi==2022.9.14
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
colorama==0.4.5
cryptography==38.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dill==0.3.5.1
Django==4.1
django-allauth==0.51.0
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-tinymce4-lite==1.8.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
isort==5.10.1
jsmin==3.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1
mccabe==0.7.0
oauthlib==3.2.1
Pillow==9.2.0
platformdirs==2.5.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.5.0
pylint==2.14.5
python3-openid==3.2.0
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tomli==2.0.1
tomlkit==0.11.1
types-cryptography==3.3.23
typing_extensions==4.3.0
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.12
whitenoise==6.2.0
wrapt==1.14.1
```

```
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422160+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinymce/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422161+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.conf.urls import url
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422161+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)
2022-09-23T13:49:34.422162+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.88.83 - - [23/Sep/2022:13:49:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
2022-09-23T13:50:02.988981+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-09-23 13:50:02 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Error handling request /
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989014+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989015+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989015+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989017+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989017+00:00 app[web.1]:     callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989018+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 313, in resolve_request
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989018+00:00 app[web.1]:     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989018+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 638, in resolve
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989018+00:00 app[web.1]:     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989019+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989019+00:00 app[web.1]:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989019+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 690, in url_patterns
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989019+00:00 app[web.1]:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989020+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989020+00:00 app[web.1]:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989021+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 683, in urlconf_module
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989021+00:00 app[web.1]:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989021+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989021+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989021+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/blog/urls.py", line 34, in <module>
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989023+00:00 app[web.1]:     path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989023+00:00 app[web.1]:     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-09-23T13:50:02.989025+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinymce/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
```

I have tried importing from django.urls import include, re_path, however that could not solve my problem as it have solved for many in other threads..

Given below is my url file .. before if..

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from posts.views import (
    index, blog, post, search,
    post_update, post_delete, post_create)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('blog/', blog, name='post-list'),
    path('search/',search, name='search'),
    path('create/', post_create, name='post-create'),
    path('post/<id>/', post, name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<id>/update/', post_update, name='post-update'),
    path('post/<id>/delete/', post_delete, name='post-delete'),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
]
```

I have been facing this problem while deploying my app on heroku, anyone can help on this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be coming from tinymce, and it doesn't look like django-tinymce4-lite supports Django 4+ yet (https://pypi.org/project/django-tinymce4-lite/).

The django-tinymce==3.5.0 package supports Django 4.0 and 4.1 (https://pypi.org/project/django-tinymce/). You might want to try that...

Comment: Thankyou for replying, while moving forward another error occured ```TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/index.html  ```Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://app1.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
templates/index.html
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during: posts.views.index

```

Comment: ```    new_signup.email = email 
        new_signup.save()
    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'latest': latest
    }
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', context) …
def blog(request):
    category_count =get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 4)'''

Comment: Even though it says so , however my templates directory is at same level as the app directory that contains views.py

Comment: That sounds like an entirely new question.

Comment: so should i post it again

Comment: Yes, please post (only that part) as a new question.